# Creating NumericTextBox with the following error is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Tags: asp.net

I know this is a classic error. I've tried to understand the error, unfortunately I can't. I also have done googling most of them are written in C# not in VB.

What I'm going to do is creating an numeric textbox where the input number will be automatically converted to currency format.

INPUT: 1000
OUTPUT shown: 1,000

My project has only following 2 files.

**1. text.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" src="cls/NumericTextbox.aspx.vb" AutoEventWireup="false"     inherits="daisystory.com.NumericTextBox" %>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >  
    <body>  
        <form id="form1" runat="server">  
            <asp:TextBox id="mytext" text="1000" onKeyPress="ValidateNumeric()" runat="server" />  
        </form>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

**2. NumericTextbox.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System  
Imports System.Web.UI  
Imports System.Web.UI.Page  
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls  
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace daisystory.com  
    Public Class NumericTextBox  
    Inherits TextBox

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "ValidateNumeric()")

            If Not (Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ValidateNumericScript")) Then           
                Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("ValidateNumericScript", "<script language='javascript'>" & chr(13) & _
                    "function ValidateNumeric(){" & chr(13) & _
                    "var keyCode = window.event.keyCode;" & chr(13) & _
                    "if (keyCode > 57 || keyCode < 48)" & chr(13) & _
                    "window.event.returnValue = false;}" & chr(13) & _
                    "</" & _
                    "script>")
            End If
            MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
        End Sub

        public overrides Property Text As String
            Get
                return(MyBase.Text)
            End Get
            Set
                MyBase.Text = Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString()
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**AND HERE is the ERROR:-**

```
Parser Error Message: 'daisystory.com.NumericTextBox' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error:  
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" src="cls/NumericTextbox.aspx.vb" AutoEventWireup="false"inherits="daisystory.com.NumericTextBox" %>
```

What should I do?
Your help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your page is not what you are trying to extend.  You want a control that is extended.  The page should just be a normal aspx page file with a [registration for the new user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab.aspx) and instead of the asp:textbox you would put your new control in it.

[Here's an article for user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx).